# Pylibnet constants

Tags: python, libnet

i am introducing myself in the pylibnet library, I want to ask you how i can get the constants imported in this code.

```
import libnet
from libnet.constants import *
```

I try help(libnet) but there are nor any answers to my problem.

Thank you!!

Comment: Please feel free to accept if my answer solves your problem, or g8ve guidance if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `dir(libnet.constants)` ?

Also `libnet.constants.__dict__` should work.

To cut down on the noise a bit you could do

```
[x for x in libnet.constants.__dict__ if x[:2] != '__' and not callable(libnet.constants.__dict__[x])]
```